# Android studio, Error OkHttp3

Tags: android, okhttp

После добавления библиотеки:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
```

в андроид студио появляется ошибка:

> Error:Could not download okhttp.jar
>   (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0): No cached version available for
>   offline mode

Я понимаю, что не удалось сделать загрузку джар файла! Как это исправить?

Comment: После ручного редактирования `build.gradle` студия в окне кода сверху показывает панель, так вот там справа `Sync` нажмите

Comment: Естественно я проводил сборку после ручного изменения! Как раз после новой сборки и выскакивает ошибка...

Answer (score 1):

- File -> Settings
- Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle
- Снимите галочку с `Offline work`
- OK
- Перезагрузите проект (Rebuild Project)